# How to lock my computer through incoming connection directly into my computer

Tags: wireless-networking, security, privacy, osx-yosemite, wifi-configuration

Im on a macbook yosemite, I usually get connected to internet through my landlord's wifi connection. How can I make sure that he cannot see or access my files in my computer (in Shared section of my Finder, I can see their computer, but cannot access it). How can I do the same, that I can prevent anyone from accessing my computer files.

What needs to be set in settings, what needs to be adjust, where in my computer should I check if someone had already viewed or accessed my files recently?

Thanks

Comment: If you search for e.g. 'yosemite sharing', you'll find several pages that cover this. E.g. [this book chapter](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2264461).

Answer (score 1):

Under system preferences, select the Sharing icon and see if you have any of the services there checked, these services allow you to share with others on the network.  If nothing is checked (On) then you should be fine in the sense that no one can easily browse files or folders.  If these services are checked, you will need to either uncheck them and stop sharing those items or specify the levels of sharing that you want to enable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the services and how to specify the level of sharing?

Comment: In the Sharing window there are 6 or more services that will be listed to allow for sharing.  Each of which when checked or highlighted will show a window to the right where you can select accounts or all users to have access to the service you are sharing.  File sharing for instance has the ability to set read only, read write and write only.  You can set these permissions for users, groups and Everyone.  Each service has specific settings so you will need to review each and determine which services you want enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [firewall](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642).

The most secure option is to configure it to [block all incoming connections](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/165).

This might however prevent some services from working. As you can see in the second link, you can also allow/forbid incoming connections on a per-service basis.